# Manipulation Searching Dictionary with list as value in Python

Tags: python, list, search, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:
`d={1:[2,3,4],2:[1,3,4],3:[1,2],4:[1,2,3]}`.

I need to do for example: In the `key 1` I have the list `[2,3,4]`. I have to count the number of connections between the element of the list as value in all the keys.

So I have to verify if in `key 2` there are as elements `3`or `4` and also the `key 3`with the element `4`.

This research has to continue for all the `key` of the dictionary `d`.

At the end of searching in all the keys, I had to count the number of the couples found. In the example I have  only `count=2` because `key 2` is connected with `3` and `4`, but `3` isn't connected to `4`. Repetitions aren't required. So I'm not interested in the couple `4-2` if I had already found (and counted) the couple `2-4`. 
I tried to implement for the first key:

```
 `
 d={}
 d={1:[2,3,4],2:[1,3,4],3:[1,2],4:[1,2,3]}
 values=[]
 count = 0 
 #for key in d:
 values = d[1]
 for value in values:
     for i in  (d[value]):
         print "i: ",i
         if i in values:
             count += 1
             print " count: ", count
             print ".........."

 print(count) 
 `
```

But, in this way `count=5` because it count also the reversed couples. I have to specify something so `count` will be `count=3`. How can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d={}
d={1:[2,3,4],2:[1,3,4],3:[1,2],4:[1,2]}
print d
values=[]
for key in d:
    count = 0
    values = d[key]
    for value in values:
       for i in  (d[value]):
            if i in values:
                count += 1
    print "count: ",count/2, " key: ", key
```